# Degree of splitting field of a polynomial over $\mathbb F_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, splitting-field

I'm trying to determine the degree of the splitting field of a polynomial over $\mathbb F_2$. I have already factorised the polynomial into irreducible factors: $f(x) = x(x+1)(x^3+x+1)(x^3-x^2+1)$

My original plan was to find the roots of the polynomial and thus find the splitting field by expanding  $\mathbb F_2$ with those roots, but my calculator is outputting some pretty strange numbers if I try to solve $x^3+x+1=0$. For example these are the [roots of x^3+x+1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM6Yx.png) I'm getting.
Is there any other way I can determine the degree of the field extension without explicitly determining the spitting field?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Could you please expand on what calculations you're performing in your calculator? What are you trying to achieve through those calculations, and in what sense are the outputs "strange"?

Comment: Just saw your edit. When you used your calculator, you were treating $x^3 + x + 1$ as a polynomial in $\mathbb Q[x]$. The roots you outputted were elements of $\mathbb C$. You should instead be treating $x^3 + x + 1$ as a polynomial in $\mathbb F_2[x]$. The roots should live in some finite field (e.g. $\mathbb F_8$).

Comment: Do you mind if I ask you a question in return? Suppose $L$ is an extension of $\mathbb F_2$, and suppose $\alpha \in L$ is a root of an _irreducible_ cubic polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb F_2[x]$. Let $\mathbb F_2(\alpha)$ be the subfield of $L$ generated by $\mathbb F_2$ and $\alpha$. Then what is the degree of the extension $\mathbb F_2(\alpha)$ over $\mathbb F_2$?

Comment: I think it's the same as the degree of $f$ because it's the minimal polynomial of the extension? So the degree of the extension is 3?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Follow-on question: Using what you just said, are you able to deduce that an irreducible cubic polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb F_2[x]$ splits completely in $\mathbb F_8$?

Comment: On a totally different note, what is the degree $8$ polynomial that you started with? Is it $x^8 - 1$, by any chance?

Comment: It splits in $\mathbb F_8$ because $2^3=8$, doesen't it? I think I remember a theorem I learnt last semster about this.

Comment: The polynominal i started with is $x^8+x$

Comment: Sorry, I meant $x^8 + x$. Have you noticed that $x^8 + x = x(x^7 - 1)$? Do you know that $\mathbb F_8$ is the splitting field of $x^7 - 1$ over $\mathbb F_2$? Many people use this characterisation as the _definition_ of $\mathbb F_8$.

Comment: Regarding the irreducible cubic, what I was getting at was that $\mathbb F_2(\alpha)$ is _isomorphic_ to $\mathbb F_8$ because $\mathbb F_8$ is the _unique_ extension of degree $3$ over $\mathbb F_2$.

Comment: I didn't know (but i couldn't attend any lectures last semester though, i don't know if this was somehow mentioned) - i'm not sure this is what i'm supposed to do here, because the first part of this was to factorise the polynomial into irreducible factors

Comment: Sorry to hear that you couldn't attend lectures. Could you please then tell us what is your preferred definition of $\mathbb F_8$?

Comment: It was always described as the field with 8 elements, that's the only definition i know of

Comment: One way of settling this is the following. $g(x)=x^3+x+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_2$ because it has no roots in $\Bbb{F}_2$. So if $\alpha$ from the splitting field satisfies the equation $\alpha^3+\alpha+1=0$, then $\Bbb{F}_2(\alpha)$ is a cubic extension. You can then verify (do check some of these to get a bit of experience with pencil & paper arithmetic in the field $\Bbb{F}_2(\alpha)$) that $\alpha^2$ and $\alpha^4=\alpha^2+\alpha$ are also zeros of $g(x)$. What about the roots of $h(x)=x^3+x^2+1$?

Comment: (cont'd) Here we can use a trick. You see that the sequence of the coefficients of $h(x)$ is the reversed sequence of the coefficients of $g(x)$. Therefore
$$h(\frac1{\alpha})=\frac{1+\alpha+\alpha^2}{\alpha^3}=\frac{g(\alpha)}{\alpha^3}=0.$$
Another consequence of $g(\alpha)=0$ is that $\alpha(\alpha^2+1)=g(\alpha)+1=1$, so you can deduce that $1/\alpha=\alpha^2+1$. You can then verify with more checking that the other roots of $h(x)$ are $\alpha+1$ and $\alpha^2+\alpha+1$. Consequently all the zeros of your polynomial are in $\Bbb{F}_2(\alpha)$.

Comment: (cont'd) As explained in Kenny Wong's (+1) answer, the zeros of the degree eight polynomial you have are exactly the elements of $\Bbb{F}_2(\alpha)\simeq\Bbb{F}_8$. Indeed, your calculator is built to work with complex numbers, so it is the wrong tool here. You wouldn't use it to find all the $3\times3$ matrices $A$ satisfying $A^3+A+I_3=0$ either, would you?

Comment: The point of my string of comments is to invite you to do such exercises in finite field arithmetic. I don't know if it is strictly necessary to be fluent with such calculations, but carrying out a few of those does build your sense of the differences as well as similarities between the arithmetic in $\Bbb{Q}$ and its extensions versus $\Bbb{F}_2$ and its extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it will be helpful to organise the discussion in the comments into something more coherent.

In my opinion, the biggest challenge is less about answering the question at hand than it is about laying out the background theory in a sensible order, taking care to avoid circular logic. For me, the most sensible starting point is to characterise the fields of the form $\mathbb F_{p^n}$, where $p$ is a prime. As mentioned in the comments, the question you asked becomes trivial once we've fully characterised $\mathbb F_{p^n}$.

**Proposition 1:** Let $L$ be a splitting field of $x^{p^n} - x$ over $\mathbb F_{p}$. Then $L$ contains $p^n$ elements.

This proves the *existence* of a field with $p^n$ elements.

*Sketch proof of Proposition 1:*

- Let $E: = \{ \alpha \in L : \alpha \text{ is a root of } x^{p^n} - x \}$. Then $E$ contains precisely $p^n$ elements. (If it were the case that $x^{p^n} - x$ has repeated roots, then $x^{p^n} - x$ and its derivative would have a common factor. But this is impossible, since the derivative of $x^{p^n} - x$ in a field of characteristic $p$ is $-1$.)
- $E$ is a field. (A consequence of the algebraic identities $(x + y)^{p^n} = x^{p^n} + y^{p^n}$ and $(xy)^{p^n} = x^{p^n}y^{p^n}$ in fields of characteristic $p$.)
- $L$ is a splitting field for $x^{p^n} - x$, so $x^{p^n} - x$ does not split completely in any proper subfield of $L$. But $E$ is a subfield of $L$ in which $x^{p^n} - x$ splits completely. Therefore, $L = E$.

**Proposition 2:** Let $L$ be a field with $p^n$ elements. Then $L$ is a splitting field of $x^{p^n} - x$ over $\mathbb F_p$.

Since splitting fields are unique up to isomorphism, this proves the *uniqueness* of the field with $p^n$ elements (up to isomorphism).

*Sketch proof of Proposition 2:* Let $L^\times$ be the multiplicative group of non-zero elements of $L$. By Lagrange's theorem, the order of every element of $L^\times$ divides $p^n - 1$. Therefore, $x^{p^n} - x = 0$ for all $x \in L$.

**Definition:** We define $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ to be the unique field containing $p^n$ elements.

This definition makes sense, because Proposition 1 proves that such a field exists, and Proposition 2 proves that such a field is unique.

Proposition 2 also tells us that $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ is a splitting field for $x^{p^n} - x$. And that answers the question you posted. The question you posted is a special case of this result, for $p = 2$ and $n = 3$.

---

However, you went about the problem in a different way. You factorised the polynomial $x^{p^n} - x$ into a product of irreducible factors (in the special case where $p = 2$ and $n = 3$). You then went about determining the splitting fields for each of the irreducible factors of this polynomial, with the intention of using this as a first step towards solving your problem.

Determining the splitting fields for irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb F_p[x]$ seems like a manageable task that we ought be able to accomplish. So I think I should explain how we might go about accomplishing this task.

I've given this more thought than I had at the time of the discussion in the comments, and unfortunately, I can't think of any reasonable way to tackle this that doesn't use Galois theory. This is because I want to use the following lemma, which I'm going to prove with Galois theory.

**Lemma:** For every $n$ that divides $m$, $\mathbb F_{p^m}$ contains a *unique* subfield that is isomorphic to $\mathbb F_{p^n}$. $\mathbb F_{p^m}$ contains no other subfields.

*Sketch proof of Lemma*:

- $\mathbb F_{p^m}$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb F_p$, since it is the splitting field for the separable polynomial $x^{p^m} - x \in \mathbb F_p[x]$.
- $Gal(\mathbb F_{p^m}, \mathbb F_p)$ is a group of order $m$.
- $Gal(\mathbb F_{p^m}, \mathbb F_p)$ is cyclic: it is generated by the Frobenius automorphism $\sigma : x \mapsto x^p$.
- Since $Gal(\mathbb F_{p^m}, \mathbb F_p)$ is cyclic, it has precisely one subgroup of order $m/n$, for each $n$ that divides $m$, and no other subgroups. By the Galois correspondence, $\mathbb F_{p^m}$ has precisely one subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb F_{p^n}$, for each $n$ that divides $m$, and no other subfields.

Using this lemma, we can prove:

**Proposition:** Let $f(x)$ be any irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ in $\mathbb F_p[x]$. Then the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb F_p$ is $\mathbb F_{p^n}$.

*Proof:* To prove this, let $L$ the splitting field of $f(x)$. Then $L$ is a finite field of characteristic $p$, so $L$ must be isomorphic to $\mathbb F_{p^m}$, for some $m$. Our task is to prove that $m = n$.

If $\alpha \in L$ is a root of $f(x)$, let $\mathbb F_p(\alpha)$ denote the smallest subfield of $L$ containing $\mathbb F_p$ and $\alpha$. Then $\mathbb F_p(\alpha)$ is an extension of degree $n$ over $\mathbb F_p$, since $\alpha$ is the root of a degree $n$ irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb F_p[x]$. So $\mathbb F_p(\alpha)$ contains $p^n$ elements, i.e. $\mathbb F_p(\alpha)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb F_{p^n}$.

But our Lemma tells us that $L$ contains a *unique* subfield $E$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb F_{p^n}$. Therefore, $E$ is equal to $\mathbb F_p(\alpha)$, for *all* roots $\alpha$ of $f(x)$. So $f(x)$ splits completely in $E$, but does not split completely in any subfield of $E$. Thus $L = E$, which completes the proof.

---

Returning to your question, you wanted to find the splitting field for a polynomial of degree $8$ in $\mathbb F_p[x]$ that factorises as a product of two linear factors and two irreducible cubic factors in $\mathbb F_p[x]$. By similar logic to the above, you can prove that the splitting field of any such polynomial is $\mathbb F_{p^3}$.

Indeed, if $L$ is the splitting field for this polynomial of degree $8$, then the splitting field for each of the irreducible cubic factors is a subfield of $L$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb F_{p^3}$. But $L$ contains a *unique* subfield $E$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb F_{p^3}$. So *both* of the irreducible cubic factors split completely in $E$ (as do the linear factors, trivially). Hence $L = E$.